# How to resume flask.session object when oath2 callback

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, flask

I'm writing Sina Weibo client via oauth2 to add authentication to current user who has already loged in with my own website's account, since OAuth2 uses a redirect-callback mechanism, it seems that after this routine, and in the Callback view handler, the flask.session is totally a new object. Thus i lost current user's log in status.

but In the same browser (like Firefox) to add a new tab and visit my site's homepage (www.funfunsay.com), the session object is still exists!

So there are two flask.session in the same browser instance???

I wrote a very simple module, it goes well with Sina weibo except that I lost the old session.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import (Flask, render_template, current_app, request,
                   flash, url_for, redirect, session, g, abort)


# For import *
__all__ = ['create_app']

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.secret_key = 'secret key'

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    print "before request:", session
    #<1st output>for first visit www.funfunsay.com, the output is: before request: <SecureCookieSession {}>
    #<3rd output>for callback from sina, the output is the same

@app.after_request
def after(response):
    print "after request:", session
    #<2nd output>for first visit www.funfunsay.com, the output is: after request: <SecureCookieSession {'testinfo': 'abc'}*>
    return response


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    print "request:", request
    login_uri = 'https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A//funfunsay.com/connect/sina/callback&response_type=code&client_id=3921006605&display=default'

    session['testinfo'] = 'abc' #a key-value for test

    return redirect(login_uri)

@app.route("/connect/sina/callback")
def connect_sina_callback():
    print "connect_sina_callback: ", session
    #<4th output>will output: connect_sina_callback:  <SecureCookieSession {}>
    return 'Callback success!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 80)
```

PS: for test purpose, I add "127.0.0.1 www.funfunsay.com" in my hosts file.

Comment: I've found this wierd phenomenon:

I use "www.my-site-addr.com" in my callback url string,

then start Firefox browser, entering "my-site-addr.com" and press enter, the session was cleared in the callback.

if start Firefox browser, entering "`www.`my-site-addr.com" and press enter, the session was still there!!!

why???

Answer (score 2):

Just keep consistency of the domain name. My solution is always use "www.my-web-site.com", if the users entering "my-web-site.com", redirect them to "www.my-web-site.com". now everything is ok!

Answer (score 0):

Flask assigns a new session to each request coming from a different point of origin- so even if the addresses resolve to the same IP, each request from a distinct starting point will be assigned a different session.  E.g. a browser window started at `http://localhost:5000` will be assigned a different session from a tab in the same browser window that is directed to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` ...even though the two resolve to the same location.

This can be frustrating, as the data in one session will not be available to the other tab in the same browser, as you would expect... while one session may happily be storing all your data as you navigate through the site, the other tab will have an empty `session` variable.

I find this most tricky when working with OAuth callbacks, when I need to ensure that the callback URL (defined on the server to which you're sending the request, e.g. when you define an OAuth application with a data provider) matches the site where I'm initiating my request.  For example, if my OAuth Application Settings in the Github API Developer page lists the callback URL as `http://localhost:5000/callback` I cannot point my browser to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` as the callback will initiate in a new session, with empty session data.

Fortunately, this is easy to debug (at least in development on `localhost`): make sure that you test your site using the same format of the host as you defined the callback URL in the data provider's OAuth Application Settings (when you define your app in the e.g. Facebook, Twitter, or Github OAuth API panel).